# How can we expose Kubernetes services to the public in AWS without using LoadBalancers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, devops, kops, amazon-elb

I'm Running a Kubernetes cluster on `AWS` using `Kops` for the first time and I need some help in exposing the services to the public with an AWS managed domain name and an SSL certificate.

The cluster is running in a private VPC and I can access it through a bastion instance.

Right now I'm exposing the services to the public using LoadBalancer service type as follow:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-gateway-service
  namespace: {{ .Values.nameSpace }}
  labels:
    app: gateway
    tier: backend
  annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: 'http'
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-port: '{{ .Values.services.sslPort }}'
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: '{{ .Values.services.sslCert }}'
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: gateway
    tier: backend
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: {{ .Values.applications.nodeAppPort }}
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: {{ .Values.applications.nodeAppPort }}
```

as you can see I'm passing the SSL certificate using annotations then I will just point the domain name to loadBalancer public ingress and done.

**The Problem:**
This Project is a micro-services project and requires a lot of services to be exposed to the public in different environments which means a lot of `AWS LoadBalancers` and a lot of Money $$$$.

I've tried NodePort and ExternalName services but none of them worked because of the private VPC.

Any suggestions to overcome this problem?

Comment: Just checking: you know about Application Load Balancer rules and target groups, right?  You can have up to 100 rules sending traffic to 100 different sets of targets behind a single ALB.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot but you can specify in kubernetes which loadBlanacer to use

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-controllers). It's basically an nginx instance that's configured programmatically via annotations. There are several others available too (e.g., kong)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you can point your `LoadBalancer` to a "reverse-proxy" service such as an NGINX instance or Istio's Gateway (https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#Gateway), the Ingress controller and other options.

That way when you hit `https://[your_service_url]/[path]` you can build rules which route to the correct internal service in Kubernetes based on the actual values of `your_service_url` or `path`.

That way you only pay for 1 Load Balancer, but can host many services in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, In this case, would the Ingress Controller load balance the traffic to the replica sets ?

Comment: No, that should be done inside the cluster: for each microservice, you should declare a `Service` which load-balances to each the `Pods` that are created as part of a `Deployment` or `StatefulSet`. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/.

Comment: Depending on your use-case, you can also deploy nginx as a `DaemonSet` to listen on 80/443 on all Nodes, and avoid the use of an ELB altogether.